# Adding lat/lon to multiple shapefiles

Tags: shapefile, r

I have location data points for colonies (csv file). I have a shapefile that I need to duplicate and georeference to each colony. Is there a way to do this in r?

EDIT: I want to create a **copy** of the existing KUD shapefile for **each** colony location. I **do not** want to create a unique KUD for each colony.

Picture shows the shapefile (green) that I am trying to replicate for each colony and have the center of the shapefile georeferenced to on the colony. Arrows show the change I want to make in the location of the shapefile.

[image]

Picture shows the data table of the colonies. They are imported as a csv file and I need to create a copy of the shapefile for each colony data point located at the same lat/lon.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GISse! Could you click "edit" and update your question with more details? What does KUD mean? What format are your data in (fields, etc)

Comment: @Simbamangu thanks! I've edited to add requested details.

Comment: Is the colony this whole band of points, or are there several colonies represented here?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by creating a KUD for each data point - a KUD is created from multiple points? Do you need a KUD for each *tag* in the CSV (i.e. from multiple points associated with a given ID)?

Comment: @Simbamangu I've used other movement data to create a KUD for bird movement during breeding. Now I want to apply this same KUD to all of the colony locations for that species of bird. Essentially need to apply different lat/lon coordinates to a shapefile and duplicate it for every colony data point.

Comment: @JepsonNomad each data point represents a separate colony location

Comment: Are you planning to generate a *unique* KUD for each colony location? Or do you want to create a *copy* of the existing KUD shapefile for each colony location? The second option should be simple to implement, but it doesn't sound correct. Wouldn't the kernal utilization density be unique for each colony? Please [edit] your question to clarify.

Comment: @csk I want to create a copy of the existing KUD shapefile for each colony location. Edited question to clarify. Thank you!

Comment: So you want to create some identical copies of this KUD shapefile? That's the only sense I can make of your question at this point. What's the KUD shapefile called? Where do you want the copies put?

Comment: @Spacedman Yes I need to create identical copies of this KUD shapefile but I need each copy to have a different georeference point (lat/lon). For each dot in the picture above there needs to be the KUD shapefile centered around it.

Comment: That doesnt make sense. Shapefiles aren't "centred" around anything, they store the geometry of a set of features. Do you really mean you are trying to draw maps centred at each point? Or you want to create a new set of shapefiles that are *cropped* from your KUD shapefile? If so, how far round each of the points do you want it?

Comment: @Spacedman I need the shapefiles to all have different georeferences that correlate to the lat/lon for each data point in the data.table.

Comment: Okay, think we're getting there. So do you know the coordinate that the shapefile is based on already? If that is (x0,y0) then its a case of translating the shapefile data by `(x_i-x0, y_i-y0)` for each of your `N` points at location `(x_i, y_i)` to produce `N` shapefiles that only differ by having the shape shifted. Yup?

Comment: EG if your KUD was a set of perfect circular rings, your output shapefiles would be the same perfect circular rings but centred on each point in that other data set.

Comment: @Spacedman yes I've tried this in ArcGIS but ran into the issue of figuring out the distance needed to move to be "centered" on the point because they weren't projected and changing the projection did not work. Is this (the distance) possible to calculate in R?

Comment: If the points are in true lat-long coordinates and you want to do everything on a sphere then a simple translation (change in lat-long) isn't appropriate because lat-long doesn't work like that (try adding 20 degrees to 75 degrees N). You can rotate in 3d a feature on the sphere to a new location but that can also result in a rotation of the feature about itself. Consider shifting Cuba to the north pole - which way do you point it? On a small scale its much easier to use projected (x-y instead of lat-long) coordinates. Is that appropriate with you here?

Comment: @Spacedman I see your point. I believe that this may be a small enough scale that using x-y would work.

Answer (score 1):

The geometry of spatial objects in the `sf` (simple features) package can be treated like matrices - and thus added / subtracted easily, and it's noted in the comments that you can treat this as a simple XY translation.

Create a basic polygon:

```
kud <- st_as_sf(data.frame(name = "poly1", 
   wkt = "Polygon ((1 1, 1 2, 2 2, 2 1, 1 1))"), 
   wkt = "wkt", crs = 4326)
```

Find the centroid

```
kud.cent <- st_centroid(kud)
```

Create a copy of the polygon then subtract the centroid's coords from the polygon's to get a polygon centred around 0,0

```
kud.0 <- kud
kud.0$wkt <- kud.0$wkt - kud.cent$wkt
```

To centre the polygon on a new point, just add that point to the '0' polygon:

```
pt1 <- st_as_sf(data.frame(name = "colony1", wkt = "POINT(3 1)"), wkt = "wkt", crs = 4326)
kud.1 <- kud.0
kud.1$name <- pt1$name # assign the name to the new poly
kud.1$wkt <- kud.1$wkt + pt1$wkt
```

For your CSV file, you could probably use:

```
colony <- read.csv("yourfile")
colony <- st_as_sf(colony, coords = c("Lon", "Lat"))
kud.1 <- kud.0
kud.1$wkt <- kud.1$wkt - colony$wkt[1]
```